# Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration' nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I had this issue and I've tried using the latest spring boot version but still cannot fix. Here is the error output

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient()" is null
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient()" is null
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used this command and it works

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```